# SQL Duplicated Row

Tags: sql

I have a duplicated row but not the same value in the all
example:

```
Name , Group , Level
SKILL_CHAR_FRONTAREA_A_01 SKILL_CHAR_FRONTAREA_A 1
SKILL_CHAR_FRONTAREA_A_02 SKILL_CHAR_FRONTAREA_A 2
```

I need to select the top one between them, using the order by level desc.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: i donn't need to select using first row inserted i need to select by the top 1 between them

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the row with the lowest or highest level value?

```
select Name , Group , min(Level)
from yourtable
group by Name , Group
```

Change min to max if you want the highest level.

Comment: no i need to select the top 1 between them

Comment: Did you even try my select??? It's portable SQL, and produces the result you want!

Comment: still yea
http://prntscr.com/5pvc8d

Comment: @jarlh this can't works: you're grouping by name and group, but in the example names are different. So you obtain 2 rows.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that minor difrerence. Sorry. I'll soon get back and edit my query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, GroupName, Level
FROM table
WHERE Level = '1'
```

Comment: hey i need to select the top 1 between them and using order not a specify varible

Comment: The top one is always level 1 according to your screenshot you posted?